# rm matching file names by pattern

Tags: linux, tcsh

I have 42000+ Project Gutenberg epubs. Often a release has both an images version and a no-images version. I want to remove the no-image copies if there is an image copy.

...
pg16045-images.epub
pg16045.epub
pg506.epub
...

In this case I would want to remove pg16045.epub because pg16045-images.epub exists, but not pg506.epub as pg506-images.epub does not exist.

How can I do this from the command line? I'm using the TCSH shell, but I can switch to BASH if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This deletes all `epub` files in `/somewhere` recursively if they do have a corresponding `-images` file.

```
find /somewhere -name '*-images.epub' -exec bash -c '
    f="${0//-images/}"
    [[ -f "$f" ]] && echo rm -- "$f"
' {} \;
```

Remove the `echo` when you're sure it's correct.

Comment: I would think there be no need to test the file's existence before removal: if "find" has located the *-images* file, then there is surely a backup.

Comment: The point is that there could be no accompanying `.epub` file without `-images`, so that's just a safeguard against that. An `rm -f` would have done the same.

Answer (score 0):

This will find all your '*-images.epub' and then tries to remove corresponding '*.epub' directory, without checking does it exist or not.

```
#!/bin/sh   

for d in *-images.epub ; do
  rmname=`echo "$d" | sed -e 's/\(.*\)-images\(\.epub\)/\1\2/'`
  echo rm "$rmname"
done

# end of file.
```

Remove 'echo' from the beginning of the line to make this actually work. It's a good idea to first echo commands to terminal and see if that's what you really want before doing things like this.

Comment: Better :) … but it'd still fail because the `$d` – the assignment to `rmname` – is not quoted. (Probably does not matter here, since the file names appear to be plain, but in case somebody uses this for different purposes.)

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps a tad shorter:

```
 find /path/to/target/directory -name '*images.epub' -exec sh -c ' echo '{}' | sed 's/-images//' | xargs  echo rm -f  ' \;
```

Comment: Why `xargs -0` when the input to `xargs` is not `NUL`-delimited?

Comment: Right... I fixed that, sometimes I just produce entropy. Need some?

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick

```
DIR="/home/xyzuser/testdir"
for i in $(ls "$DIR");
do
  if [[ "$i" == *.images.epub  ]]
  then
    var=${i%.*}
    var=${var%.*}
    if [[ -f "$DIR/$var.epub" ]]
    then
      rm "$DIR/$var.epub"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Just change the DIR value to wherever your files are. If you're storing this script in a file, don't forget to make it executable with

```
chmod +x filename.sh
```

. Otherwise, you will not be able to run it.
What it does is basically.

1. Loops through all the file(name)s
2. If a file has "images.pub" it cuts out the ".images.epub" part from it's file name
3. Then it checks if any file with an ".epub" suffix (end part) has the current ".images.epub" file's prefix (start part). And if found, it deletes it.

Comment: Please read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs